# Prim's Maze Generation Runtime

Tags: maze, prims-algorithm

I wrote a Prim's Maze generator using equal rates so that it is almost entirely random. I have benchmarked the algorithm and found it to have a running time of O(5n). This equates to a 290 second run time to generate a 128 x 128 maze.

My question is, is this a good run time? Is this high, low, average? I have a feeling the slowdown is more to do with caching the nodes of the maze then in the relatively lightweight integer comparisons. I just want to do get an idea of whether I have a decent implementation or if it is just too slow.

Comment: I get the feeling this question would be better on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JayC Posted there as well, no one likes runtime analysis haha.